# Incrementing row references in Excel formulas

Tags: excel-formula

In my excel sheet I need to expand my vertical range by one row. For instance, I need my `C` column to look like this (after 14th row):

`C14`--to be--> `=NPV(B1, B9, B14:B14)`

`C15`--to be--> `=NPV(B1, B9, B14:B15)`

`C16`--to be--> `=NPV(B1, B9, B14:B16)`

and so on.

What is the proper way of relative addressing for cell `C14`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make everything but the last component of the range absolute:

```
=NPV($B$1, $B$9, $B$14:B14)
```